# Generate the files into a different package pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

Here follows my folders hierarchy:

```
|-src
|  |-main
|  |  |-java
|  |  |  |-pt.thales.attracktive.communication
|  |  |  |  |-pojo
|  |  |  |  |  |-...
|  |  
|  |-resources
|  |  |-...
|
|-target
|  |-generate-sources
|  |  |-xjc
|  |  |  |-uk.org.siri.siri
|  |  |  |  |-...
```

I'm generating .xsd files to .java. Usually they are going to target/generate-sources/xjc/uk.org.siri.siri but I was able to send them to src/main/java/pt.thales.communication/attracktive.communication/pojo. The problem is that they go with the package name uk.org.siri.siri and that creates conflit. I wish to update the package name in the code but thats depends of what's inside the .xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

How can I change that in the pom.xml?

Comment: Which Maven plugin do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to configure the target package name in the `pom.xml`, but I don't recomment it. Because it configures one target package for everything - and JAXB works better when you follow "1:1 namespace:package" logic.

The way I recommend is using binding files.

If you're using [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin), just create a file named `bindings.xjb` (or anything with `*.xjb`) in `src/main/resources`. The contents would be like:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.acme.foo"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

`schemaLocation` must point to one of the schema files of your schema.
`jaxb:package/@name` defines the target package name.

If you have several namespaces create a separate `jaxb:bindings` (with `jaxb:schemaBindings/jaxb:package` per namespace. Point `schemaLocation` to some schema file which uses the specific namespace.

I do not recommend mapping several namespaces onto one package, this often leads to problems.

Comment: Tanks a lot!! More info: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configure-Target-Packages-in-Binding-Files